# Fetch data from one row(which has more data inside ) into coulmns in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i want to fetch data from one row which has more data inside it separated by space from website, then how can i fetch this data into excel and convert it into columns by using selenium webdriver ?

My Code:

```
WebElement Table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='schemeGridHolder']/div/div[6]/div/table"));
List<WebElement> rows = Table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
Iterator<WebElement> i = rows.iterator();
int x=0;
while(i.hasNext())
{
    WebElement row = i.next();
    List<WebElement> columns = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    Iterator<WebElement> j = columns.iterator();
    int y=1;
    while(j.hasNext())
    {
        WebElement column = j.next();
        System.out.println(column.getText());
        Row dataRow = sheet23.createRow((short)x);
        System.out.println("x="+""+x);
        System.out.println("y="+""+y);
        Cell cell12 = dataRow.createCell(y);
        cell12.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell12.setCellValue(column.getText());
        y=y+1;
    }
    x=x+1;
}
```

HTMLCode:

```
    <table>
<tr>
<td colspan="100">
<div>Name</div>
<div class="clearfix scheme-name">
<a id="name-2019-7993063096" class="" target="new">
Alice Lopez
</a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix header-resp">
Id no
</div>
<div id="sch-inv-2019-7993063096" class="clearfix scheme-mtm" data-v-min="-999999999.99" data-d-group="2">
AS4567H
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="100">
<div>Name</div>
<div class="clearfix scheme-name">
<a id="name-2019-7993063096" class="" target="new">
John Stark
</a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix header-resp">
Id no
</div>
<div id="sch-inv-2019-7993063096" class="clearfix scheme-mtm" data-v-min="-999999999.99" data-d-group="2">
B8765M
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But in excel it display all data in single row because in that particular website data is also in single row which is separated by div tag and when i open my excel it also display all data in single row For Example ,
[ExcelFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abO6t.png)

from that excel i want to remove Id no .....what should i do ?

Comment: You need to provide some example of what you have done.

Comment: sir , i have edited my question ....please check again !!

Comment: Sounds like you need to parse the text of the HTML row and split it whenever the row separator (div-tag) appears. Add some of the HTML code to your question, so it is easier to help you.